# Upload image to server from android volley via php

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I am trying to upload an image to my server but can't seem to get it to work. I am using android and volley to get the image and then sending it to the php to upload.

I am using wamp as well.

Says "successfully uploaded" but is not in the directory?

PHP CODE:

```
<?php

     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

         $image = $_POST['image'];
         $username = $_POST['username'];
         require_once('dbConnect.php');
         $sql ="SELECT profilepictureID FROM tbl_userprofilepictures ORDER BY profilepictureID ASC";
         $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
         $profilepictureID = 0;

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
             $profilepictureID = $row['profilepictureID'];
         }

         $path = "000001/$profilepictureID.JPG";
         $actualpath = "http://*wamp server ip*/Users/Images/$path";

         $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_userprofilepictures(username,profilepicturepath) VALUES ('$username','$actualpath')";

         if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
             file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
             echo "Successfully Uploaded";
         }

         mysqli_close($con);
     } else{
         echo "Error";
     }

 ?>
```

Comment: check permissions on the folder path for storing images.

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?